# Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game not found?

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop, xna-3.0

I've been programming in C# on my Uni Laptop which conveniently does not allow any installations.

Regardless, using ShaprDevelopPortable I was working on a project when I noticed `Microsoft.Xna.Framework 3.0` in the search list for references. I immediately tried a to compile the default template for `XNA-4.0` when I received these errors:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. (MSB3247)
The type or namespace name 'Game' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) 
The type or namespace name 'GraphicsDeviceManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
The type or namespace name 'GameTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
The type or namespace name 'GameTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

Now I don't know if the functionality of `GameTime` has been removed from `XNA-3.0` to `XNA-4.0` but surely `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` would still be there?

Note that the version of SharpDevelop I'm using is 4.2 (and it is portable) so I'm wondering if the reasons I'm getting this error is:

- Microsoft XNA is not properly installed
- or a Problem with SharpDevelop

And if there is any solution for my problem that doesn't require Admin rights or Installation.

Comment: Would you go into a boxing match with one hand tied behind your back? Why are you developing on a machine with so many restrictions ?

Comment: @Noctis Well I'm not gonna carry my desktop around with me! I understand this is a lot of restrictions and I'm not having much trouble working with SharpDevelop for simple projects, its just that compiling XNA on my laptop would allow me to do most of my programming on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Without the ability to install the required `XNA` libraries in the the `GAC`, Global Assembly Cache, **and** the `DirectX` Libraries, it is not possible to run an `XNA` program.

If the required `Directx` Libraries are installed, it is possible to run an `XNA` program as long as all of the required `DLL`s are co-located in the same directory with the executable. This is not the default configuration, and will require manually copying the files to the output directory(the same as the .exe file, which overrides the GAC).

This is the standard `DLL` distribution model for `MonoGame`.